# remove commas from tuples in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have the list of tuples

```
items = [('Abkhazian',), ('Afar',), ('Afrikaans',), ('Albanian',), ('Amharic',), ('Arabic',), ('Armenian',), ...]
```

and want to make it

```
['Abkhazian', 'Afar', 'Afrikaans', 'Albanian', 'Amharic', 'Arabic', 'Armenian', ... ]
```

Currently the only solution I've found is as follows

```
items = [str[i] for item in items]
for i in range(len(items)):
    items[i] = items[i].replace("[","")
    items[i] = items[i].replace("(","")
    items[i] = items[i].replace("'","")
    items[i] = items[i].replace(",","")
    items[i] = items[i].replace(")","")
    items[i] = items[i].replace("]","")
```

I feel like there should be a better way

Answer (score 6):

Hm, there's no comma in the items, it's just single element tuples you got there.

If you need to not have single element tuples in the list and, instead, have them as string entries, just use a list comprehension:

```
res = [item[0] for item in items]
```

where you select the first item out of every tuple in the original list.

```
print(res)
['Abkhazian', 'Afar', 'Afrikaans', 'Albanian', 'Amharic', 'Arabic', 'Armenian']
```

You actually  do get a nice speed-up with @ShadowRanger's slick unpacking alternative:

```
res = [item for item, in items]
```

might seem like a typo but it gets the job done.

Comment: Trivial variation (could be faster for large inputs by pushing more work to C layer, haven't tested): `from operator import itemgetter` at top of file, the do `list(map(itemgetter(0), items))` (can omit `list` wrapping on Py2). Or a variant list comprehension that ensures you really have only one item in each `tuple` using sequence unpacking, `[item for item, in items]`; tested that one as about 20% lower runtime on Python 3.5 (indexing is surprisingly slow in Python), and it should be faster no matter how large or small `items` is.

Answer (score 0):

On a more Pythonic side, you can unzip the list:

```
items = list(list(zip(*items))[0])
```

Comment: Using `zip` to undo single element `tuple`s is not "Pythonic". It works, but calling it Pythonic is a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [i[0] for i in items]
print (result)
```

nothing fancy and no commas that look like typos